# How can I store a <HashMap<MyCompositeKeyClass, ArrayList<MyClass>> in SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, hashmap, sharedpreferences, gson

I wish to store an HashMap which contains MyCompositeKeyClass as key and  ArrayList as value inside SharedPreferences. How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
 public void saveLessonMap(Context context, HashMap<dayKey, ArrayList<Lesson>> lessonMap){
   MapWrapper wrapper = new MapWrapper(lessonMap);
   String serializedMap = gson.toJson(wrapper);

    appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();

    prefsEditor.putString(KEY, serializedMap);
    prefsEditor.commit();


}

 public HashMap<dayKey, ArrayList<Lesson>> getLessonMap(Context context){
    appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String wrapperStr = appSharedPrefs.getString(KEY, "");
    MapWrapper wrapper = gson.fromJson(wrapperStr, MapWrapper.class);
    return wrapper.getMap();
}
```

But got:

```
fromJson com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 10
```

JSON: `{"map":{"com.example.ruslanposhuk.timetable.model.dayKey@ca81be1c":[{"bTime":{"year":2015,"month":4,"dayOfMonth":7,"hourOfDay":8,"minute":30,"second":0},"eTime":{"year":2015,"month":4,"dayOfMonth":7,"hourOfDay":9,"minute":50,"second":0},"name":"Wednesday1","room":"114","teacherName":"John Smith"},{"bTime":{"year":2015,"month":4,"dayOfMonth":7,"hourOfDay":10,"minute":0,"second":0},"eTime":{"year":2015,"month":4,"dayOfMonth":7,"hourOfDay":11,"minute":20,"second":0},"name":"Wednesday2","room":"254","teacherName":"Bob Moore"},{"bTime":{"year":2015,"month":4,"dayOfMonth":7,"hourOfDay":12,"minute":0,"second":0},"eTime":{"year":2015,"month":4,"dayOfMonth":7,"hourOfDay":13,"minute":20,"second":0},"name":"Wednesday3","room":"178","teacherName":"Peter Johnson"}],"com.example.ruslanposhuk.timetable.model.dayKey@28f78912":[{"bTime":{"year":2015,"month":4,"dayOfMonth":7,"hourOfDay":8,"minute":30,"second":0},"eTime":{"year":2015,"month":4,"dayOfMonth":7,"hourOfDay":9,"minute":50,"second":0},"name":"Tuesday1","room":"114","teacherName":"John Smith"},{"bTime":{"year":2015,"month":4,"dayOfMonth":7,"hourOfDay":10,"minute":0,"second":0},"eTime"]}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Gson gson  =
        new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().setPrettyPrinting().create();
java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken <HashMap<dayKey, ArrayList<Lesson>>>(){}.getType();
```

Saving: `String json = gson.toJson(lessonMap, type);`

Loading: `HashMap<dayKey, ArrayList<Lesson>> lessonMap = gson.fromJson(json, type);`

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `ArryList<MyClass>` to json data and store it.  Use gson library to convert ArrayList to JSON String format.